# Is there a way to export JetBrains Datalore notebooks

Tags: jupyter-notebook, datalore

Is there a way to export JetBrains Datalore notebooks to any format (preferably PDF)?

I have looked at Jupyter notebook solutions but could not find a way to implement them in Datalore and I also tried to make Jupyter more like Datalore (auto-completing latex and code and side by side view) but did not find a way to do this as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can export it as a PDF from the File menu tab
[pdf export](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XSraB.png)

Answer (score 2):

You can export to .ipynb: File -> Export .ipynb, and then use nbconvert.

[image]

Datalore itself doesn't support PDF yet